# Proxy blocking Javascript SDK (all.js)

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, sdk

I am using Javascript SDK in order to add a register box in my site, but... I was wondering, at least, here in Spain, lots of companies block Facebook site, so... how can I detect if user was unable to load all.js, and show my default register box??

I tried js loaders like HeadJS or LAB.JS but I couldn't manage to get it to work. or things like checking typeof of some variables of all.js but nothing worked

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    if (!window.FB) {
        // Whoops, all.js couldn't be loaded for *some* reason... assume blocked.
    } 
</script>
```